# Android Kotlin app not write data properly to firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have an Android app that write data to Firebase realtime database, It is working properly if I install app on my phone in debug mode directly using cable, but its not working properly when I publish the app in play store.

Expected in database
[image]

## here is my code to send the data to firebase realtime database

```
locationClient.getLocationUpdates(1000L)
            .catch { e -> e.printStackTrace() }
            .onEach { location ->
                Log.d("LocationService", "Got location: $location")
                 lat = location.latitude
                 lng = location.longitude
                val updatedNotification = notification.setContentText(
                    "Location : ($lat , $lng)"
                )
                if (currentUser != null){
                    val email = currentUser.email.toString()
                    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
                    val date = Date()
                    val current = formatter.format(date)
                    val data = LocationData(email, lat, lng, "online", current)
                    myRef.child("locations").child(currentUser.uid).setValue(data)

                }
                notificationManager.notify(1, updatedNotification.build())
            }
            .launchIn(serviceScope)
        startForeground(1, notification.build())
```

## my data class

```
package com.knoworganization.safeair_kotlin.location

data class LocationData(
    var email: String,
    var latitude: Double,
    var longitude: Double,
    var status: String,
    var timestamp: String,
)
```

I have tried to republish the app but it still not working. And my app if perfectly configured with firebase. I don't see anything in Firebase Crashlytics as well.

Comment: First check if you have proguard enabled on release mode. 
If yes then you have to exclude the data classes,so that it will not be shrinked. 

I believe the data class was shrinked by proguard and that's why you are getting the params name like that.

Comment: "it's not working properly when I publish the app in Play Store" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors? Besides that, have you tried what itsgenius_thulc adviced you?

Comment: @itsgenius_thulc yes progaurd is enabled, How do I exclude data class in it...?

Comment: I will post it as an answer for your convinence.

Comment: @itsgenius_thulc I tried excluding the data class in progaurd rules, but it didn't work for generated signed Bundle/APK. 
Then I set  " isMinifyEnabled = false " in build.gradle, now its working fine but my app size is increased

Comment: I have provided the solution below, check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude your model class in the proguard rules, do the following

First check the path of the model class in your android project structure.

```
com.knoworganization.safeair_kotlin.location
```

This is the path to your data class.

so you can write the following on the proguard rules

```
-keepclassmembers com.knoworganization.safeair_kotlin.location.** { *; }
```

this will allow your data class to stay same on the release mode as well.

If you have more data class which are not needed to be shrinked, then you can enter the package direclty, like below.

```
-keepclassmembers com.knoworganization.safeair_kotlin.** { *; }
```

check with this and let us know, if this works for you.

Comment: ohh its " -keepclassmembers" , I had written only "-keep"

Comment: You can try annotating the class with @Keep as well.

Comment: `-keepclassmembers com.knoworganization.safeair_kotlin.** { *; } `
was giving me an error so wrote it like this 
`-keepclassmembers class com.knoworganization.safeair_kotlin.location.** { *; }`
(Added class keyword)
Now its working properly and my app is also minified.

**Thank you @itsgenius_thulc**